# Vue.js - v-if vs v-text with a ternary operator?

Tags: vuejs2

What would be the point of using v-if if you can use a ternary inside v-text?

e.g

```
<span v-text="data.value ? data.value : '-'"></span>
```

As opposed to:

```
<span v-if="data.value" v-text="data.value"></span>
<span v-else >-</span>
```

The first uses less markup.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ternary is the best solution in my opinion. You should use `v-if` if you want to show different content or another component.

```
<div class="searchResults" v-if="data.results.length">
    <!-- show results -->
</div>
<div class="useful-links" v-else>
    <!-- Show some useful links, useful information or even adds when no results are found -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-if` is used when you want to add or remove an element from the DOM. Using a ternary operator or even the `v-show` will keep the element on the DOM and toggle whether the content is displayed or not.